# Alfresco: Few of the db files corrupted

Tags: alfresco

Few of the db files corrupted and showing 0kb as file size, Is there a way to get back those files and make my alfresco instance up and running.

Kindly suggest what is the best solution to get data back.

Comment: Exactly which files are showing 0kb in size? Do you have a backup you can recover from?

Comment: alf_data/postresql>Base>16386>16882, 16883 and few more I got to know about these files from the alfresco log file as couldn’t open file “base/16386/16877” invalid argument.The file is corrupted and I did dskchk and content got deleted and the file size becomes 0. Unfortunately I have not taken backup. Since 15days back I had installed and data is in TBs

Comment: Cross-posted here: https://community.alfresco.com/thread/238969-unable-to-login-in-alfresco-52